# How Can use TextField like Wrap in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My rule is

1. Don't allow newLine(enter)
2. But, Text as long as 'device width' in TextField, It set newLine like 'Wrap' widget.

Can I?

Comment: Is that a question or a straight up request? What kind of research and implementations had you tried so far?

Comment: I tried maxLines, but It not work my expect. Both rule must be true. It so complex @MarianoZorrilla

Comment: update your question with a code you have tried.. perhaps a mockup picture of what you want achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `inputFormatters` property of your `TextFormField`, also need to add `maxLines: null`

see full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(child: SomeWidget()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      inputFormatters: [BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'[\n\r]'))],
      maxLines: null,
    );
  }
}
```